# Mixed background color for a web page using html, css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Can someone please tell me how to make a mixed background color for a web page using html, css or bootstrap. Is there any property for this?
I went through background-blend-mode, but this is not what I am looking for.
I am trying to create background color of my entire webpage similar to the below website:
[https://www.learncodeonline.in](https://www.learncodeonline.in/)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried css gradient?

background-image: linear-gradient(direction, color-stop1, color-stop2, ...);

Answer (score 0):

I checked the website you linked and they are not using any background color property or gradient. They are using images that are placed as background-image.

Answer (score 0):

The mention website is using following technologies to make there website.
If you want to create your website in this format then use the following web framework.
or your can create without this framework also but its gonna take a while to create those animations and all.

I hope you got your answer

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, will check it. I am using React for the website.